# svnadumpfilter only the lasts 10 revision

Tags: svn, backup, dump, svnadmin

I have a svn repository that I backup with

svnadmin dump myrepo | gzip -9 > myrepo-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T").dump.gz

hourly (I'm a little crazy).

There is a way for dump the last only 10 or 20 revision of the svn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- svndumpfilter has nothing common with revision ranges,
- `svnadmin dump` can be used with `-r LOWER:UPPER` option,
- `svnlook youngest` give you latest revision in repo.